# Interpreting equation of a plane

Tags: calculus

I have encountered a question on multiple integrals in which the equation $x=2y$ is referred to as a vertical plane. How can we interpret the equation $x=2y$ as the equation of a plane? How will it look like?

Comment: The general equation of a plane is: $$a x+b y+c z+d=0$$. In your case $a=1,b=-2,c=0,d=0$

Comment: Have you tried it, show where you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x-2y+0z=0$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plane+x%3D2y

$\vec{n}=\{1,-2,0\}$

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a 3D axes with any point being define by the function x = 2y. Any point is given by (x,y,z). Using some 3D graphing software could show you how it *will look*. [image]